# Connection takes over 1 min while sqlplus to the database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

while us sqlplus to connect the database,it always takes about 1 mins.
I used the command

```
strace -T -t -0 /tmp/s.out sqlplus user/pwd@dbname"
```

,and find it takes 40s here

```
read(13, "\0\10\0\0\v\0\0\0", 8208) = 8
```

the connection should be connected within 1s.

Comment: It could be many things. Network problems, database host is CPU slammed, a login trigger is doing something expensive, LDAP authentication is being used and there's an issue communicating with the LDAP server, the shared pool is messed up and there's a mess of blocking waits wreaking havoc on everybody, etc... or even a problem on your client. Reach out to your DBA to have them check their end.